# I am following a PostgreSQL tutorial. Cannot get results from psql --help inside psql shell

Tags: postgresql, zsh, psql

I am following a long a [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qw--VYLpxG4) on PostgreSQL

Within the video the teacher has led me to download PostgreSQL 13. I know have pgAdmin 4 and SQL Shell psql. I've been able to follow the teacher all the way until 33:42. Right before that I was able to follow along in the shell and create a database. Then the video cuts and I notice he does not seem to be in the same psql shell and is now in a shell with zsh at the top.

I'm on a Windows machine and I am a beginner and do not know what shell this is. The instructor then continues to type `psql --help`. However when I type that same command I am not able to get the same results thus I am not able to continue to follow along. What do I need to do to proceed?

Teacher's shell before video cut:

[image]

Teacher's shell after the video cut, shell looks like it says zsh:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The next screen shows a new shell. Just exit your current session and start a new shell.

Comment: Ive done that and when I type psql --help nothing happens. I assume its because he is using an entirely different shell. The first picture shows psql shell and the next shell says zsh at the top, I am following along in psql shell so I am  sure the reason why I cannot generate the same results is because he is in zsh shell and I am in psql shell, right?

Comment: You don't need that really. `--help` just gives you a quick synopsis of the `psql` options. The [online documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html). contains all that information.